# How to setup a Cron job to do a Git commit

Tags: git, shell

I have been manually committing my git repository everyday. But then sometimes I forget.

Is it possible to write a shell script to do a git commit ?

I am finding it difficult because I dont know how to provide the commit message through script.

**NOTE**

I am thankful to all the developers who have pointed out to me that this is not the way a version control system is supposed to be used. I agree. If I do a daily commit many of the versions will remain in broken state.

My case is different. I am not really interested in maintaining versions that wont break. I am more interested in keeping backup of my code. I work in a weird way on a remote machine through winSCP. 
I want something that will save every minor change I make so that just in case I do 'rm -rf' in some directory I wont lose most of my work.

Comment: It's better to do commits based on units of work done, not on days. The idea of a script that commits automatically at the end of the day kinda scares me.

Comment: A possible alternative: A cron job that looks at your git repo every few hours, and if you have more than X lines worth of changes, and you haven't committed in the past Y hours, it alerts you somehow saying, "I noticed you haven't committed anything in a while, maybe you should..."

Comment: Take a look at `flashbake` http://www.boingboing.net/2009/02/13/flashbake-free-versi.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not seem like a very good idea, but, if you still want to do it, something like this would suffice:

```
COMMIT = cat ~/commit_message
git commit -m $COMMIT
```

And, you can change `~/commit_message` to whatever you like everyday.

Comment: And then your problem becomes forgetting to set the commit_message every day. I agree with Uku Loskit that this defeats the purpose of a version control system

Comment: Yes, I would also encourage you to not do this. If you could give us a bit more information on what your goal is, we could help you. cronjobs really don't fit everywhere.

Comment: Your answer is not syntactically valid sh.  Did you mean COMMIT=$(cat ~/commit_message) ?  If so, why not just git commit -F ~/commit_message.  Since I'm commenting, I should chime in and agree that committing to git automatically is a terrible, *terrible* idea.

Comment: I would agree with William Pursell.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what your exact use case is, you might want to take a look at [Flashbake](http://bitbucketlabs.net/flashbake/) which uses git to do very frequent commits of a project - the idea is to help authors track their writing progress at a very fine level.  It's not how git was designed to be used, but it's quite a nice idea :)

Comment: yeah, I need exactly something like that. Thanks1

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't differ from a run-of-the-mill cronjob much. You can set the commit-message via the `-m` (message) option.

This being said, it seems odd that you would want to commit regularly like that. If you always commit with the same message and a non-separable amount of work, that kind of goes against the whole idea of version control.

Comment: I agree that that is not the way version control system are supposed to be used but this case is very specific one.

Comment: One scenario is backing up config files in version control. In that case, you keep committing every day or whatever time interval you choose.

Comment: @manojlds: I'm committing my config files only when I change them. But maybe you are having some automatically changing config files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's that terrible of an idea to have some kind of version control as a backup.

It's just another use for Git than what it was specifically intended for.

Why should you use tools you aren't familiar with already to do your heavy lifting? Maybe there is a better practice approach, but using Git is arguably comparable to any other "backing up" mechanism, it just does it through another method. As long as you understand this and understand the implications it has on the repo, have at it.

EDIT

I didn't provide an answer in my response... Sorry about that.

I'd definitely say a good approach is to instead have it run a check maybe twice a day for the number of changes, and if the number is above a certain threshold, go ahead and run a commit. Set the commit message to be something descriptive of a backup. For instance, instead of using straight bash, you could programmatically set your commit message to include the date/time and some semblance of the files that the commit changed. This way, your commit messages aren't the same, and they are actually useful.

Fairly simple to do with Python or Ruby, which both have libraries for also running command line level things (like `Git commit -am` + message, or something similar)